# RSA algorithm, relationship of the plaintext $m$ with $p$

Tags: rsa

I am studying the RSA algorithm. If for example the plaintext $m$ has some relationship with prime $p$, let's say $m$ is multiple of $p$ (where $p$ is the $p$ in $n=p \times q$). Can this give an attacker some information given we know ciphertext $y$ and public key?

Comment: Is it Textbook RSA? does the attacker know there is a relation?

Comment: Yes it is. And yes the attacker knows this relation.

Comment: No the adversary does not know that. No other information for p.

Comment: Hint (clarified): Identify **two** quantities that the adversary knows and that $p$ divides. What qualification can you give to $p$ w.r.t. theses two quantities?

Comment: Is $m$ being a multiple of $p$ the only possible relation?

Comment: Yes. e and n are known and the ciphertext.

Comment: Is this a homework question? If not we can provide an answer if you already not found it. If you found please write your answer!

Comment: I did :) I will write the answer. Thank you kelalaka

Comment: Also, clarify your question under the comments. and don't forget to add `@` before the nickname so that the comment can appear in inbox of the person.

Answer (score 1):

So after trying a few examples with small numbers, it turns out that if message $m$ is a multiple of $p$, $m=a\times p$ then $\gcd(y,n)=p$, where y the known ciphertext. The rest is easy to compute.

Comment: Yes it is $e$. Yes $y$ was  better if we assume that $y=(mp)^e \bmod n$

Comment: @fgrieu forgive me for the confusion. In my initial question I wrote m as the message and in my answer I meant x as the message. I corrected it.

Comment: That's now much better! Beware however that you did not really give an explicit proof that $\gcd(y,n)=p$, and that you need the unstated $m\ne0$ (or equivalently $y\ne0$) for that to hold.

Comment: @fgrieu you are right. This is not a proof for sure. It seems to work for different examples but I would also like to know more.

Comment: You can prove that if $m$ is a multiple of $p$ and in $[1,n)$, so is $y=m^e\bmod n$ (hint: if $r\equiv s\pmod u$ and $v$ divides $u$, then $r\equiv s\pmod v$). Then that $\gcd(y,n)$ is a positive multiple of $p$. Then that it is $\gcd(y,n)=p$.

Comment: since $m=ap$ and $y=m^{e}\pmod{n}$ then $y = m^{e}+kn.$ So $\gcd(y,n)=\gcd(m^{e},n).$ Now assume that $q\not{|}a$, then $\gcd(m^{e},n)=p$.